# Grails quartz manual triggering not working

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

I am trying to trigger a job manually from integration test class but the job is not getting triggered

Here is my code :

QUARTZ JOB :

```
package com.example.home

class OrderConfirmationEmailJob {
    static triggers = {}
    def execute(context) {
        println  "example" + new Date()
    }
}
```

Integration test  :

```
package com.example.home

class OrderConfirmationEmailServiceIntegrationTests {   
    OrderConfirmationEmailService orderConfirmationEmailService

    @Test
    void testSomething() {
        OrderConfirmationEmailJob.triggerNow(['key': 'Value'])
    }
}
```

The job is not getting triggered. What am I missing here?

Comment: I experienced the same behavior using compile ":quartz:1.0.2" plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using grails-quartz-plugin 1.0.1 you couldn't use "triggerNow()" method because isn't not implemented. If you are using quartz2 scheduler plugin and you want to create your own job class, as it is written in [documentation](https://github.com/9ci/grails-quartz2),

> the plugin will set's the grailsAppication and appCtx
>   (applicationContext) into "global" property into the schedules
>   context. Quartz, by default , uses the   PropertySettingJobFactory
>   which will attempt to inject the properties by keyName that    exists
>   in the schedule;s context, jobs context or triggers context into the
>   Job when   it creates it. So that mean if you setup your own Job and
>   need the appCtx or   grailsApplication just declare a field and it
>   will get set.

hope this help

Comment: Thanks you are right. But triggerNow() method is available from version 1.0-RC9 [May help others]

Comment: Why do you say it is not implemented in grails-quartz-plugin v1.0.1? What is [this](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-quartz/blob/master/QuartzGrailsPlugin.groovy#L228)? @vicky

Comment: Sorry, i make a mistake. The "triggerNow([params])" method isn't implemented yet.

Comment: mmm ... trying to use MyJobClass.triggerNow(); it does not works this is for compile ":quartz:1.0.2" plugin??